# vue.js store data into list from dynamically created fields

Tags: javascript, list, vue.js, dynamic

[dynamically created fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJIYt.png)

Hi, the image above shows dynamically created fields I'm using. You can add or delete the fields with the button at the right.

My goal is to

1. store data that are input to these dynamically created fields into a list
2. bind the data / display the data at a confirmation page before submitting

The expected result is that when I key in data to these fields, it will display on the confirmation page before submitting the form

I've tried using v-model, but this only works for normal fields. Here's there code for what I have now

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(line, index) in lines" :key="index" class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-2">
            <q-select
              v-model="line.countryCode"
              label="Country Code"
              :options="countryPhoneCodes"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="col-10">
            <q-input
              v-model="line.number"
              label="Phone Number"
              placeholder="5551234567"
              type="tel"
              value=""
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <q-select
          v-model="line.phoneUsageType"
          label="Type of Usage"
          :options="phoneUsageTypes"
        />
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div class="block float-right">
          <q-btn round @click="removeLine(index)" icon="delete" />
          <q-btn round v-if="index + 1 === lines.length" @click="addLine" icon="playlist-plus" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'PhoneNumberLine',
  data () {
    return {
      lines: [],
      blockRemoval: true,
      phoneUsageTypes: [
        {
          label: 'Home', value: 'home'
        }, {
          label: 'Work', value: 'work'
        }, {
          label: 'Mobile', value: 'mobile'
        }, {
          label: 'Fax', value: 'fax'
        }
      ],
      countryPhoneCodes: [
        {
          label: '+90',
          value: '+90'
        }, {
          label: '+1',
          value: '+1'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  watch: {
    lines () {
      this.blockRemoval = this.lines.length <= 1
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addLine () {
      let checkEmptyLines = this.lines.filter(line => line.number === null)
      if (checkEmptyLines.length >= 1 && this.lines.length > 0) {
        return
      }
      this.lines.push({
        countryCode: null,
        number: null,
        phoneUsageType: null
      })
    },
    removeLine (lineId) {
      if (!this.blockRemoval) {
        this.lines.splice(lineId, 1)
      }
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.addLine()
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be similar to what you are trying to achieve. tweak it to fit your needs. good luck.

```js
const makeLine = (n = 0) => ({
  number: n
});

new Vue({
  name: "App",
  template: `
    <div>
      <div class="line" v-for="(line, idx) in lines" :key="idx">
          <input v-model="line.number" />
          <button @click="addLine" v-if="lines.length - 1 === idx">+</button>
          <button @click="removeLine(idx)" v-if="lines.length > 1">-</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      lines: [
        makeLine(),
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addLine() {
      this.lines.push(makeLine(this.lines.length));
    },
    removeLine(idx) {
      this.lines = this.lines.filter((_, id) => id !== idx);
    }
  }
}).$mount("#app");
```

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.line {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```